# numpy.float128 doesn't exist in windows, but is called from OpenGL

Tags: python, windows, numpy, opengl, pyopengl

I decided to try using OpenGL VBO in Python to improve FPS. I found code, that worked perfectly fine in Linux OS (Ubuntu), but when I tried launching in Windows OS, the code resulted in a message:
"GLUT Display callback  with (),{} failed: returning None module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128'"

So, I can't run the code specifically on Windows, but because I want to create a cross-platform application, I really need to solve this.

I've done a lot of research and only found that numpy.float128 should be replaced to numpy.longdouble. However, because OpenGL VBO is in opengl_accelerate, I don't know how to change the usage there.

This is my entire code.

```py
import sys
import random #for random numbers
from OpenGL.GL import * #for definition of points
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import * #for visualization in a window
import numpy as np


AMOUNT = 10
DIMENSION = 3

def changePoints(points):
    for i in range(0, 3*AMOUNT):
        x = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
        points[i]= points[i]*x
    print(points)
    return points

def displayPoints(points):
    vbo=GLuint(0) # init the Buffer in Python!
    glGenBuffers(1, vbo) # generate a buffer for the vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo) #bind the vertex buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sys.getsizeof(points), points, GL_STREAM_DRAW)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo) #bind the vertex buffer

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) # enable Vertex Array
    glVertexPointer(DIMENSION, GL_FLOAT,0, ctypes.cast(0, ctypes.c_void_p))
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo) #bind the vertex buffer
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, AMOUNT)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) # disable the Vertex Array
    glDeleteBuffers(1, vbo)

##creates Points
def Point():

    points = np.array([random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0) for _ in range(3*AMOUNT)], dtype = np.float32)

    points = changePoints(points)

    #Visualization
    displayPoints(points)


##clears the color and depth Buffer, call Point() and swap the buffers of the current window
def display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    Point()
    glutSwapBuffers()

def main():
    ##initials GLUT
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    #sets the initial display mode (selects a RGBA mode window; selects a double buffered window; selects a window with a depth buffer)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    #defines the size of the Window
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 1600)
    #creates a window with title
    glutCreateWindow(b'Points') #!string as title is causing a error, because underneath the PyOpenGL call is an old-school C function expecting ASCII text. Solution: pass the string in byte format.
    glutDisplayFunc(display) #sets the display callback for the current window.
    glutMainLoop() #enters the GLUT event processing loop.

main()
```

This is the full error traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
>       return function( *args, **named )
>     File "C:/Users/root/Desktop/test/main3.py", line 48, in display
>       Point()
>     File "C:/Users/root/Desktop/test/main3.py", line 42, in Point
>       displayPoints(points)
>     File "C:/Users/root/Desktop/test/main3.py", line 23, in displayPoints
>       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sys.getsizeof(points), points, GL_STREAM_DRAW)
>     File "src/latebind.pyx", line 44, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.Curry.**call**
>     File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\VERSION\GL_1_5.py", line 86, in glBufferData
>       data = ArrayDatatype.asArray( data )
>     File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 172, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.ArrayDatatype.asArray
>     File "src/arraydatatype.pyx", line 47, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.HandlerRegistry.c_lookup
>     File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 16, in load
>       return importByName( self.import_path )
>     File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\plugins.py", line 38, in importByName
>       module = **import**( ".".join(moduleName), {}, {}, moduleName)
>     File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\arrays\numpymodule.py", line 27, in 
>       from OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler import NumpyHandler
>     File "src/numpy_formathandler.pyx", line 55, in init OpenGL_accelerate.numpy_formathandler
>   AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128'
>   GLUT Display callback  with (),{} failed: returning None module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128'

Is there any way of either changing the usage of numpy.float128 to numpy.longdouble in opengl_accelerate or making numpy.float128 work in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found possible solution:
I found out that PyOpenGL’s last version works fine itself, however, it’s pyopengl-accelerate package that causes this issue to appear. After I removed the acceleration package everything world fine.