# How to define np.float128 variable in python?

Tags: python, double

In the most upvoted answer to the question [Double precision floating values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663272/double-precision-floating-values-in-python) it is mentioned that we can use np.float128, if we need precision more than standard float. But I couldn't find a way to do this.

Then, in the most upvoted answer to [how to declare variable type, C style in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933197/how-to-declare-variable-type-c-style-in-python), use of typing is suggested.

However, when I tried to use typing to set the datatype as float for a integer type value, Python still used an int data type.

```
n : float=10000
print(type(n))
```

But still, the result is :

```
<class 'int'>
```

So, How can I define np.float128 type variable in python?

Comment: *Variables* don't have types in Python; *values* do, and 10000 is perfectly representable as an `int`.

Comment: variables aren't typed in python. Python is a dynamically typed language. Type hints *are hints to people reading the source code*, or for use by third-party static type checkers. The Python runtime itself ignores them, basically. You want to create a `np.float128` *object*, but are you sure that's what you want? Why not `decimal.Decimal`, which supports arbitrary precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
from numpy import float128

n=float128(10000)

print(type(n))
```

Print:

```
<class 'numpy.float128'>
```

Bear in mind that there are some issues using `numpy.float128` on Windows 64-bit (see [numpy.float128 doesn't exist in windows, but is called from OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686018/numpy-float128-doesnt-exist-in-windows-but-is-called-from-opengl)). I have tested this code in an online Python editor.